# Alterar a cor da linha de um EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho um `Layout` simulando uma tela de PIN (tipo uma *lockscreen*), onde eu tenho um `EditText`. Estou usando a `AppCompat v21` para poder usar os elementos estilo Material. Porém, quero definir somente nessa tela de PIN a cor de destaque (*accent*) para o `EditText`, sem alterar todo o projeto.

Atualmente, esse é o meu arquivo `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigo</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigo_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Quero com que somente o EditText da tela de PIN use a cor branca no destaque. O resto do app quero que tenha outra cor, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Existe alguma tag que preciso usar? Tem como fazer isso via código?

Comment: Renan, pelo que eu vi, está previsto nos próximas versões do **AppCompat** o atributo `theme` para os widgets (atualmente só o `Toolbar` possui essa funcionalidade). No Android Lollipop isso já é suportado. Mais detalhes em: https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O gerador [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) pode te ajudar nesta tarefa, ou você pode criar seu próprio **drawable** para definir como fundo do seu `EditText`, mas envolve mais elementos como cor de foco, desabilitado e etc.

Por exemplo, se quiser apenas uma cor sólida da borda inferior, crie um arquivo **bg_pin.xml** no diretório `res/drawable` assim:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <!-- cor da borda -->
  <item>
      <shape>
          <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- cor de fundo, tamanho somente da borda inferior -->
  <item android:bottom="1dp">
      <shape>
          <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

E então, no layout do seu XML onde quiser aplicar o estilo, algo assim:

```
<EditText
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/bg_pin" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a forma mais correta seria você criar uma derivação do tema principal do projeto para essa tela, pois se outras mudanças forem necessárias nela, você não tem que ficar criando arquivos específicos, mas apenas mudar no tema para essa tela.

Supondo que seu tema se chame `AppTheme`.

Eu criaria um tema  para essa tela e nela eu definiria o `colorAcent`.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Pin" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">cor desejada</item>
</style>
```

Depois, basta ir no `Androidmanifest.xml` e especificar que para essa Activity, o tema será esse:

```
 <activity  android:name=".PinActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Pin"/>
```

Se quiser, pode informar via código também, dentro do método `onCreate`:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Pin);
```